# Junit Test case for File import

Tags: java, junit, file-import

I have a file import functionality in the web application. I need to write junit test case to test the import. I have searched through the web for a junit test case for similar scenario but unable to find. Appreciate any input on this.

Comment: It's an Unit test so your test would include a prepared file to be imported. The file should cover all possible cases ( correct data, incorrect data etc ) and the start the importing in the test and perform assets if the data is there and if the expected exceptions etc get thrown.
Maybe this will help you a little bit: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762576/junit-tests-using-a-mock-database

Comment: As written up right now, your question is too broad. Put up (some) of your production code; and show what you tried to test about it.